# checking NULL not working

Tags: iphone, ios, rest, null

I'm checking to see if the items in this dictionary (which are returned from the server) are NULL, like this:

```
    NSString *imageURL = [userDict objectForKey:@"image_url"];
    NSString *userName = [userDict objectForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *typeName = [userDict objectForKey:@"type"];

    if (imageURL == NULL || userName == NULL || typeName  == NULL || imageURL.length == 0) {
        localImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
        [addAnnotation setTitle:@"Something"];
        [addAnnotation setSubTitle:@"Wrong"];
    }
```

However, in one record (the above is in a for loop) `[userDict objectForKey:@"image_url"]` returns `"<null>"` but is not getting handled correctly in the if statement above. Why isn't my null check working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if([userDict objectForKey:@"image_url"] == nil)
```

Use this:

```
if([userDict objectForKey:@"image_url"] == [NSNull null])
```

That works just fine when you deal with dictionaries that are returned by JSON deserializers or similar.

Answer (score 1):

try comparing instead to

`[NSNull null]`

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries return null objects you can check for them using `[NSNull null]` so this way you are comparing to null objects. `Null` should be used for non-object pointers. `nil` is used for objective-c `id` type.

Answer (score 0):

Check for all Null like `if(object==[NSNull null]||object==NULL||object==nil)`.It will check for all type.So You don't need to be specific.